# Multiple dependent select

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have installed [Simple hierarchical select](https://drupal.org/project/shs) module ,and added category field in one content type and also gave multiple hierarchical taxonomy.

but this module is not responding properly when i click on add content and trying to select items from taxonomy than i am only able to see and select sub term of the first term.

please suggest something.

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Bug in the module which should be reported in D.O Module Issue Queue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead use [Hierarchical Select](https://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module, like anil mentioned report a bug for SHS module.

> Hierarchical Select has the ability to save the entire lineage of a
>   selection or only the "deepest" selection. You can configure it to
>   force the user to make a selection as deep as possible in the tree, or
>   allow the user to select an item anywhere in the tree. Levels can be
>   labeled, you can configure limit the number of items that can be
>   selected, configure a title for the dropbox, choose a site-wide
>   animation delay, and so on. You can even create new items and levels
>   through Hierarchical Select!

Comment: I did'nt get you..this is all about SHS but is their solution to rectify this bug.